# ASP.NET MVC passing data to partial view through ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar library, where I load my events as JSON and display them in the calendar.
What I would like to do next is to load an id of the latest event and display information about the event from the model in the partial view. This is my code so far:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<div id="myPartial"></div>

<script>
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        aspectRatio: 3,     
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetEvents")", function (locationsArray) {
                var result = $(locationsArray).map(function () {
                    return {
                        id: this.idEvent,
                        title: this.eventName,
                        start: this.startTime,
                        end: this.endTime,
                        allDay: this.allDay
                    };
                }).toArray();
                callback(result);
                var id_latest = result[result.length - 1].id
                success: $(function (id_latest) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddContent","Home")',
                        data: { id: id_latest },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("An error occurred.");
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#myPartial").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });               
    });           
    }
    });
</script>
```

What am I missing here? What is the proper way to do it?

Edit:

Controller:

```
    namespace bezeckaApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddContent(int? id)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/AddContent.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult GetEvents()
        {
            List<Treninky> trenink = new List<Treninky>();
            trenink.Add(new Treninky() { idEvent = 1,  eventName = "Morning run", startTime = "2017-07-01T08:00:00Z", endTime = "2017-07-01T09:00:00", allDay = false });
            trenink.Add(new Treninky() { idEvent = 2, eventName = "Evening run", startTime = "2017-07-05T17:00:00Z", endTime = "2017-07-05T18:00:00", allDay = false });
            trenink.Add(new Treninky() { idEvent = 3, eventName = "Evening run", startTime = "2017-07-08T17:00:00Z", endTime = "2017-07-08T18:00:00", allDay = false });

            return Json(trenink, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace bezeckaApp.Models
{
    public class Treninky
    {
        public int idEvent { set; get; }
        public string eventName { set; get; }
        public string startTime { set; get; }
        public string endTime { set; get; }
        public bool allDay { set; get; }


    }
}
```

**EDIT**

this still causes *id* in AddContent method NULL

Comment: Could you share your full code including your model & controller?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you have.  Are you getting errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Then my problem is probably about understanding how to use the value in my partial view.

Comment: what do you mean by " the latest event ", or "understanding how to use the value in my partial view"? Which event are you referring to? Which value? Are you asking how to display information about a specific event after a user clicks on it in the calendar?

Comment: By "the latest event" I mean event with the latest or the newest date and "understanding how to use the value in my partial view" is issue how to pass id of the event to a partial so I can display proper information from model. My idea is basically display the event with the newest date though the partial view when the page is loaded (my current problem posted here). My next step will be to allow click on the specific event and display data in the same partial view. To sum up: last event when the page is loaded, then update the partial view on the event click.

Comment: are the events in the event feed guaranteed to be returned in order with the newest one last? I appreciate right now you've only got hard-coded sample data, but what's your intention once it's fully implemented? On the face of it there's no reason the code shouldn't work, except you need to change the AddContent method to accept an "id" parameter, fetch an appropriate event object as a model and pass that model to the partial.

Comment: There will be a database which will contain much more data not just basic information. I was thinking about making sure the data are loaded in order with the newest one last. Do you have a different recommendation for that? Because I have little experience with this, there is a possibility the solution will be too complicated.

Comment: No, that would make sense to put the newest one last. Once you make the changes to the AddContent method as I suggested then what you have got should work. If you struggle with that at all please edit the question with your attempt and describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult AddContent(int? id)
{
 List<Treninky> trenink = new List<Treninky>();
            trenink.Add(new Treninky() { idEvent = 1,  eventName = "Morning run", startTime = "2017-07-01T08:00:00Z", endTime = "2017-07-01T09:00:00", allDay = false });
            trenink.Add(new Treninky() { idEvent = 2, eventName = "Evening run", startTime = "2017-07-05T17:00:00Z", endTime = "2017-07-05T18:00:00", allDay = false });
            trenink.Add(new Treninky() { idEvent = 3, eventName = "Evening run", startTime = "2017-07-08T17:00:00Z", endTime = "2017-07-08T18:00:00", allDay = false });

  return PartialView("~/Views/Home/AddContent.cshtml",trenink.Find(id));
}
```

If yours javascript is working, and you getting latest ID then it should work.